# Using webpack with subpage JS files

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I have multiple JS files that I use for subpages. I have one JS file for the index page and one JS file for each subpage. How can I use webpack to load each JS file?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use webpack bundles and chunks: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#multiple-entry-chunks

Not sure exactly what will better match your needs, so read the documentation.

The simplest case if only to define multiple `entry` for your application; one entry per page. Then you load the chunk you needs for each pages.